# QNetworkAccessManager gives ssl errors on arch

Tags: c++, linux, qt, archlinux

I want to use QNetworkAccessManager to access a page via https, but when I try it I get the following output:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve ERR_free_strings  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init   
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_new_null  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_push  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get_ex_new_index  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain      
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve  OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf      
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay_version  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function    CRYPTO_num_locks   
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function  CRYPTO_set_id_callback  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init   
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLeay  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function  SSLeay_version
```

I'm using arch x86_64 and QT 5.9.

After typed in a terminal: `openssl version -v` I got
`OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017`, so it's the newest.

I added to main.cpp also:

```
qDebug() << "SSL version use for build "
         << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();
qDebug() <<"SSL version use for run-time "
         << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionNumber();
```

and I got the following:

```
SSL version use for build:  "OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013"
SSL version use for run-time:  0
```

Do you have any suggestions what can I do it to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of `OpenSSL` installed on your host

`QNetworkAccessManager` tries to find the functions in the lib which is loaded at runtime.

Most probably you have old version of `OpenSSL` installed.

Also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480724/use-openssl-in-qt-c#39497754) on `Qt` vs `OpenSSL` compile-time/run-time dependencies